# Полный путь к конфигу Apache (OpenServer) в Windows

Tags: windows, apache, веб-сервер, openserver, настройки

Я гуглил [конфиг apache](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%20apache&newwindow=1&sxsrf=AJOqlzUH8zmDXn9BeFRX0tybOE70gVqo2w%3A1679396657557&source=hp&ei=MY8ZZIiuH5uMxc8P26CgiAQ&iflsig=AK50M_UAAAAAZBmdQVJQ8Ft362Zi5kCH21ahJW28Uekp&oq=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%20apa&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYATIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjoECCMQJzoLCAAQgAQQsQMQgwE6CAgAELEDEIMBOg4ILhCABBCxAxCDARDUAjoICC4Q1AIQgAQ6CwguEIAEELEDEIMBOhEILhCABBCxAxCDARDHARDRAzoOCC4QgwEQ1AIQsQMQgAQ6EQguEIMBEMcBELEDENEDEIAEOgsILhCxAxCDARDUAjoICC4QsQMQgwE6CwguEIMBELEDEIAEOggIABCABBCxAzoECAAQAzoICC4QgAQQsQNQAFibLmDrS2gAcAB4AIAB1QGIAakKkgEFMC45LjGYAQCgAQE&sclient=gws-wiz), где находится конфиг apache Openserver, но в результатах везде было написано для Linux. Какой полный путь для конфига apache (Opensever) в Windows?
Спрашиваю в связи с ответом Юрия Воронина на [Из за чего не подключаются стандартные скрипты и стили в админке Битрикс?](https://qna.habr.com/q/700449)
. Путь к openServer - `C:\Openserver`, есть также путь - `C:\Apache24\`. Файлы `httpd.conf` располагаются как в той, так и в другой папке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конфиг `Apache` в `OpenServer` можно открыть, щелкнув на флажок, затем `Дополнительно->Конфигурация->Apache_2.4-PHP_7.0-7.1`.